# Accessing Map value in a separate JSTL loop

Tags: java, jsp, dictionary, jstl

Assume that a query result exists called `resultSet` having a field available as `templateId`.

Also, a map 'templateMap' exists with keys of `templatedId`.

I am not able to get any result from the following, any help appreciated.

```
<c:foreach var="row" items="${resultSet.rows}">
  <c:out value="${templateMap[row.templateId]}" />
</c:foreach>
```

Note: this is a coding horror application, wherein the above resultset is a result of `<sql:query>`.

Following doesn't work either.

```
<c:foreach var="row" items="${resultSet.rows}">
  <c:set var="tmplId" value="${row.templateId}" />
  <c:out value="${templateMap[tmplId]}" />
</c:foreach>
```

Comment: Where exactly is the `Map` in this story? The `${template}` is here just a row of the `${resultSet}`. Aren't you overriding an already-existing `Map` with the same name in the scope? Or are you confusing `${resultSet}` as being the `Map`?

Comment: Thank you for the edit. I undeleted my answer :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The code you posted (and edited) is syntactically valid, so the problem lies somewhere else.

To start, the `Id` suffix makes me think it's actually a [`Number`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Number.html). Fact is, non-decimal numbers in EL defaults to `long`. Thus, if it were a `Map<Integer, Integer>`, then this code won't work. You need to have a `Map<Long, Long>` or `Map<Long, Integer>` to get it to work.

I am not sure how I should interpret your wording "coding horror application", but I bet that you already know that using JSTL SQL taglib for other purposes than quick prototyping is considered a very bad practice ;) That logic belongs in real Java classes in the data access layer.

Comment: Thanks for that, it got me on the right track. Map is actually <String, String> and the templateId is BigDecimal. 
Regarding the coding horror. I have worked on various application of myriad complexities in my career. This one takes the cake... Everybody has to do dirty stuff once in a while... :)